# How can this for loop code work? (pandas, jupyter, python)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop, scanpy

i am a student working in bioinformatics using scanpy, python. During finding marker genes, i was going to make a data frame.
The following is the code.

pd.DataFrame({group + '_' + key[:1] : result[key][group]
for group in groups for key in ['names', 'pvals']}).head(5)

My question here are two:

1. the for statement does not have a ':' mark
2. and the naming of the 'group' and 'key' is done after, how does it affect the previous one(group + '_' + key[:1] : result[key][group])?

I want to understand the code.

Comment: Look into dictionary comprehensions.

Comment: This is a special syntax that replaces a classical loop. As said above it is called a "*dictionary comprehension*".

Answer (score 0):

What exists in Python is that in order to create and use the list, **it is not important be named before use**. Just taking a name from it while working is enough for Python

Comment: Then do you mean that the order in which variables are created and used does not matter?

Comment: @JJUN you can ignore this answer, it is incorrect. Read about dictionary comprehensions